# Creating a variable that will be accessible from anywhere in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I'm trying to create a Dark Mode in React.
For that I need a "mega-variable" that will be accessible
from anywhere on the component tree and look like :

```
let darkMode = false
```

and when that will be toggled, in a chosen component I will have the 
ability to write something like that :

```
<button>{darkMode ? "Light Mode" : "Dark Mode"}</button>
```

I tried to do it with MobX but it didn't work. 
It doesn't re-render like in a state change. 
What can I do?

Comment: why not use `window`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful with `global variables`. Actually given React's flow it's pretty hard to even achieve that (perhaps using `window` object?). What you want could be done using `Context API`. It's a decoupled way to pass `props` through your components. By wrapping the highest level of your application with a `Provider` you could access it from anywhere (inside the same tree):

```
const {Provider, Consumer} = React.createContext()

const App = () =>{
    <Provider value={{theme: 'dark'}}>
        <MyComponents />
    </Provider>
}
```

And inside any component from this tree:

```
const Component = () =>{
    return(
        <Consumer>
          {context => console.log(context.theme) /*dark*/}
        </Consumer>
    )
}
```

There are other alternatives like `redux` but seems an overkill to your use case.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know about this.

Comment: Here is the [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) from the official docs, it's very straightforward. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would use redux for that.

It lets you create and interact with state on a global level.